# Does Sidewinder have an ending?

Tags: amiga, sidewinder

Sidewinder is a shoot-em-up game, originally for arcade systems based on the Amiga and subsequently released for that platform on floppy disk. I think there might have been an Atari ST port but I'm mostly interested in the Amiga original.

I only ever completed all levels of this game on the default normal difficulty mode, and the game wraps back to level 1 but on hard mode settings. I could never finish it on hard mode.

Does the game have a proper ending if you complete all levels on hard mode? Or is it just an endless loop?